# jq animate volatile value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create an animation for showing `div` elements with different amount of content in them. The `divs` start with 0 height and width and the goal is to **first** expand the width and **then calculate the scrollHeight** so i can divide it by 2 and split the height animation as follows.

```
let t = modal.position().top;
let h = 0;
modal.animate({width: '60%'}, 'fast').queue(function (next){
    h = this.scrollHeight / 2; // Calculate at this point!
    next();
}).animate({height : h }, 'fast').animate({height: (h * 2), top: (t-h)}, 'fast');
```

This doesn't work the way I expected it. 2nd and 3rd animations consider `h` to be 0! Any ideas/help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently the way to go is via the callback:

```
let t = modal.position().top;
modal.animate({width: '60%'}, 'fast', 'linear', function(){
            let h = this.scrollHeight / 2;
            $(this).animate({height: h}, 'fast')
                   .animate({height: (h * 2), top: (t - h)}, 'fast');
        });
```